# If $\lVert f(t) \rVert:[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, is $f$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:[0,T] \to X$ be a mapping to a Banach space $X$. If its norm $\lVert f(t) \rVert$ is measurable, is $f$ itself measurable? The converse is true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. We don't even need to leave Euclidean space. Let $V$ be a nonmeasurable set in $[0,T]$. Consider the map $f: \mathbb [0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that is $1$ on $V$ and $-1$ on $V^c$. Then $|f|$ is a constant function and surely measurable, but $f$ is not.

Comment: Quick note: The poster asks for an onto function in the question, but in a later comment says the function does not need to be surjective. This example can be modified as indicated by Andres Caicedo above if a surjective function is required.

Comment: Do you know any conditions in which the answer is yes? Not sure if there any.

Comment: @matt.w I don't think there are any natural ones. Do you have a specific application in mind?

Comment: Well basically I have $X$ a Hilbert space and I have that a norm is measurable with finite Bochner norm. But I don't have that the function itself is measurable yet..

Comment: You might want to post your specific problem as another question. I don't know anything about Bochner spaces, but someone else might.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: consider cases where $f$ has just two possible values.

Comment: (And if you don't see how this applies, since you require $f$ to be onto, note that if $f$ is measurable, then there is a measurable $g$ such that $f=\|f\|g$.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I don't require it to be onto, I meant "onto a Banach space" in a different context.

Comment: @matt.w Onto means surjective. If you don't mean that, you should edit the question.

Comment: @Potato Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @matt.w "Into" would be read as injective. Just say "to a Banach space", that will remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo thanks, done. Should be more careful!!